# Check response of validation in codeception

Tags: php, codeception

I created, using laravel, a php with this method:

```
  public function register(Request $request) {
    try {
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->input(), [
                    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users_x_communities',
                    'first_name' => array('required', 'regex:/^[\pL\s]+$/u'),
                    'last_name' => array('required', 'regex:/^[\pL\s]+$/u'),
                    'community_id' => 'required|exists:communities,id',
                        ], [
                    'email.required' => 'El correo electrónico es requerido.',
                    'email.email' => 'El correo electrónico es inválido.',
                    'email.unique' => 'El correo electrónico ya esta en uso.',
                    'first_name.required' => 'Los nombres son requeridos.',
                    'first_name.regex' => 'Los nombres deben ser un texto.',
                    'last_name.required' => 'Los apellidos son requeridos.',
                    'last_name.regex' => 'Los apellidos deben ser un texto.',
                    'community_id.required' => 'La comunidad es requerida.',
                    'community_id.exists' => 'La comunidad no existe.'
                        ]
        );
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->errorBadRequest($validator->messages());
        }
        $email = strtolower($request->get('email'));
        $firstName = $request->get('first_name');
        $lastName = $request->get('last_name');
        $communityId = $request->get('community_id');
        $status = $this->auth->register($firstName, $lastName, $email, $communityId);
        $message = "OK!";

        return $this->response->array(compact('status', 'message'));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error('AuthController@register: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return $this->validException($e);
    }
}
```

Im interested in making some test in codeception to validate my function, in this case that the 4 fields, email, first_name, last_name and community_id are required.

ive managed this in codeception (ResgisterCest.php):

```
    public function validateifmailisrequired(ApiTester $I) //200
    {

            //Method created to validate if the mail is required

            $I->wantTo('Validate that the mail field is required');
            $I->sendPOST($this->url, [
                'email' => '',
            ]);

    }
```

But im kind of new and im not quite sure how to check the response that the email, for example, is required. Im new in this and a bit confused with codeception... how can i achive this? to have codeception tell me that if i sendPost with an empty mail returns me a response of field required or some response that let me test that my email and others are required....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [seeResponseContainsJson](http://codeception.com/docs/modules/REST#seeResponseContainsJson) method.

```
$I->sendPOST($this->url, ['email' => '']);
$I->seeResponseContainsJson(['error' => 'El correo electrónico es requerido.']);
```

Make the structure of expected array match the structure of response
(but don't specify all keys, only those that matter for this test).

Comment: i get a HUGE red screen on console and a [InvalidArgumentException] Invalid json: can you help me please, im having a hard time with this, not getting it full and its been like 4 days stuck in this. thanks

Comment: Please add a complete exception message to your question, an issue is with your response.

Comment: well i get the  [InvalidArgumentException] Invalid json:  \<!DOCTYPE html>
\<html>
    \<head>...
followed by what looks like an entire html page (i havent made views since im doing just api test) and at the end it says syntax error... its too long to paste it here...

Comment: You have to figure out why your url returns HTML. Maybe you need to set some request headers before making request, e.g. $I->haveHttpHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

Comment: i have this on my RegisterCest.php

    public function _before(ApiTester $I) {
        $I->haveHttpHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    }

shouldnt this take care fo that?

Comment: it tells web server what you are sending, but it doesn't tell what you expect to get back.

Comment: I am not familiar with Laravel, you have to do something like https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-51-404-response-to-json?page=1

Comment: idk what i did but it seems to be working now... gonna tag this as the correct answer, thx for the help